# Establish Wifi on startup

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, remote-control, wifi-configuration

I have a Windows7 enterprise computer with a wifi dongle on it. I would like to establish a wifi on startup (before login) that is visible for other computers and awaiting (wpa2 secured) connections.

The purpose is, I can connect to the wifi with another computer and use remote desktop (or at least VNC) to control the first one. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What Wi-Fi device is this? You should not need to log in for network interfaces to come up, whether they're wireless or not.

Comment: Yepp, you can. See this Link: **http://superuser.com/a/133935/218300**

Comment: The difference to http://superuser.com/a/133935/218300 is, that the network does not exist. The computer has to create a network on startup. 

The Wi-Fi device is Realtek RTL8188CU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter